# cryptographic algorithm encryption homework

Tags: algorithm, encryption, cryptography, password-encryption

As part of an assignment we were asked to write our own cryptographic algorithm for encrypting a password.

We are not allowed to use any of the predefined methods such as `md5` or `sha1` etc, Google seems to be no help, can somebody show me an example to links to some information?

Comment: So you want us to do your assignment for you ?

Comment: The assignment is basically an attempt for you to do some work on your own, specifically worded to not use "the internet" to do the work for you.  And yet here you are.  As soon as we define the work for you, you can't use it, because then you just copied it from some website somewhere (in this case Stackoverflow).

Comment: no i would not like you to do it, just asking for some advice or previous examples so i can understand it better. thank you

Comment: I would also like to point out that `md5` and `sha1` are hashing algorithms, not encryption algorithms

Comment: okay sorry i am a new to stackoverflow

Comment: This seems like a very misguided assignment.  You should **never** implement your own password or crypto system and should instead use a well-tested implementation.

Comment: could anybody recommend a book or website please?really baffled by the term cryptography

Comment: https://www.coursera.org/course/crypto

Comment: @templatetypedef: of course you should. for educational reasons. how can you understand something better than if you did it yourself! and thats exactly the case here

Comment: @fix_likes_coding The problem is that creating your own hash function takes years of experience. So I don't see what people would learn doing this. On the other hand it might encourage some to actually use their own algorithm, which is a *really* bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

I will assume that you are asked to come up with a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). You can just start from this Wikipedia article and have a look at different existing cryptographic hash function and their construction principles; Wikipedia has quite detailed explanations and some good links. Here some articles you should read.

- [Cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)
- [Collision resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistance)
- [Collision attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack)
- [Birthday attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack)
- [Preimage attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack)
- [Avalanche effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect)
- [Merkle–Damgård construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction)
- [One-way compression function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function)
- [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)
- [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1)
- [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2)

This should give you some understanding of commonly used cryptographic hash function of the MD4 family. There are other ways to construct cryptographic hash functions, for example using the [sponge construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sponge_function) as in [SHA-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3).

While reading through all this stuff you will probably soon realize that your chances to come up with your own (not totally broken) cryptographic hash function are very close to zero but you will at least have learned something about this topic.

One last thought - it is especially enlightening to have a look at existing attacks against cryptographic primitives because they usually exploit a tiny detailed that many smart people missed before or present a radically different way to look at something.

Comment: There was one young student who actually took part in the SHA-3 competition. It was amazing how fast his well thought out scheme was taken apart. It could be that the teacher is actually trying to show how difficult it is to create something cryptographically secure.

Answer (score 0):

I explain the AES ECB implementation in [this blog post](http://cipriano-sanchez.blogspot.de/2010/11/blog-post.html). In this other there is a more technical explanation of the [AES Round Steps](http://cipriano-sanchez.blogspot.de/2010/11/aes-round-steps.html). As well in [here](http://cipriano-sanchez.blogspot.de/search/label/aes) you can find a C implementation of it.

I hope it helps